# Laravel DataTables doesn't show any results

Tags: laravel, datatables

I was following this guide to show all partners in my admin section: https://yajrabox.com/docs/laravel-datatables/master/quick-starter

Unfortunately, there are no errors, but I don't see also the list with all items. There are results in the database, but for me, it seems it is not making the query, that's why there are no results (in the debuggbar i don't see a query with the 'partners' table).

route.php

```
Route::get('partners', [PartnerController::class, 'index'])->name('partners.index');
```

PartnerController:

```
namespace App\Domains\Partner\Http\Controllers\Backend;

use App\Domains\Partner\DataTable\PartnersDataTable;
use App\Domains\Partner\Models\Partner;
use App\Domains\Partner\Services\PartnerService;
use App\Http\Controllers\Controller;
use Illuminate\Http\Request;

class PartnerController extends Controller
{

    public function index(PartnersDataTable $dataTable)
    {
        return $dataTable->render('backend.partner.index');
    }
    
}
```

PartnersDataTable:

```
namespace App\Domains\Partner\DataTable;

use App\Domains\Partner\Models\Partner;
use Yajra\DataTables\Html\Button;
use Yajra\DataTables\Html\Column;
use Yajra\DataTables\Html\Editor\Editor;
use Yajra\DataTables\Html\Editor\Fields;
use Yajra\DataTables\Services\DataTable;

class PartnersDataTable extends DataTable
{
    /**
     * Build DataTable class.
     *
     * @param mixed $query Results from query() method.
     * @return \Yajra\DataTables\DataTableAbstract
     */
    public function dataTable($query)
    {
        return datatables()
            ->eloquent($query);
    }

    public function query(Partner $model)
    {
        return $model->newQuery();
    }

    /**
     * Optional method if you want to use html builder.
     *
     * @return \Yajra\DataTables\Html\Builder
     */
    public function html()
    {
        return $this->builder()
                    ->setTableId('partners-table')
                    ->columns($this->getColumns())
                    ->minifiedAjax()
                    ->dom('Bfrtip')
                    ->orderBy(1)
                    ->buttons(
                        Button::make('create'),
                        Button::make('export'),
                        Button::make('print'),
                        Button::make('reset'),
                        Button::make('reload')
                    );
    }

    /**
     * Get columns.
     *
     * @return array
     */
    protected function getColumns()
    {
        return [
            Column::make('id'),
            Column::make('title'),
        ];
    }

    /**
     * Get filename for export.
     *
     * @return string
     */
    protected function filename()
    {
        return 'Users_' . date('YmdHis');
    }
}
```

index.blade.php:

```
@extends('backend.layouts.app')

@section('title', __('Partners'))

@section('breadcrumb-links')

@endsection

@section('content')

<x-backend.card>
    <x-slot name="header">
        @lang('Partners')
    </x-slot>

    @if ($logged_in_user->hasAllAccess())
        <x-slot name="headerActions">
            <x-utils.link
                icon="c-icon cil-plus"
                class="card-header-action"
                :href="route('admin.partners.create')"
                :text="__('Create partner')"
            />
        </x-slot>
    @endif

    <x-slot name="body">
        {!! $dataTable->table() !!}
    </x-slot>
</x-backend.card>
    
@endsection

@push('after-scripts')
<script src="{{ asset('vendor/datatables/buttons.server-side.js') }}"></script>
{{$dataTable->scripts()}}
@endpush
```

Here is what is $dataTable->scripts() producing:

```
<script src="http://kitty/vendor/datatables/buttons.server-side.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">$(function(){window.LaravelDataTables=window.LaravelDataTables||{};window.LaravelDataTables["partners-table"]=$("#partners-table").DataTable({"serverSide":true,"processing":true,"ajax":{"url":"http:\/\/kitty\/admin\/partners","type":"GET","data":function(data) {
            for (var i = 0, len = data.columns.length; i < len; i++) {
                if (!data.columns[i].search.value) delete data.columns[i].search;
                if (data.columns[i].searchable === true) delete data.columns[i].searchable;
                if (data.columns[i].orderable === true) delete data.columns[i].orderable;
                if (data.columns[i].data === data.columns[i].name) delete data.columns[i].name;
            }
            delete data.search.regex;}},"columns":[{"data":"id","name":"id","title":"Id","orderable":true,"searchable":true},{"data":"title","name":"title","title":"Title","orderable":true,"searchable":true}],"dom":"Bfrtip","order":[[1,"desc"]],"buttons":[{"extend":"create"},{"extend":"export"},{"extend":"print"},{"extend":"reset"},{"extend":"reload"}]});});
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

the reason why your data isn't displaying on the table is because of this line of code:

```
  ->buttons(
                        Button::make('create'),
                        Button::make('export'),
                        Button::make('print'),
                        Button::make('reset'),
                        Button::make('reload')
                    );
```

comment this line of code and the data will be displayed properly.